# Как выводить не все таксономии на странице, а по три (как post_per_page)?

Tags: wordpress

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать следующую задачу.

Создал свой тип записи, и свою таксономию, вывожу таксономии следующим образом:

```
`введите сюда код`<?php
   $terms = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy'      => array( 'post_tag', 'fitnescat' ), 
  'order'         => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty'    => true,  
  'hierarchical'  => true,
  ) );

  foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
              <div><?php echo $term->name ?></div>
               <div><?php echo $term->description ?></div>
                <div>Уроков:<?php echo $term->count ?></div>  
              <h4><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ) ?>">Подробнее</a></h4> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Все отрабатывает нормально, но нужно выводить не все таксономии на странице, а по три. Нужно сделать что-то типа post_per_page, однако в функции get_terms() так не получается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вывод таксономий постранично

```
$tax_per_page = 3;
$offset = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$offset = ( $offset - 1 ) * $tax_per_page;

$args = [
   'taxonomy' => [ 'post_tag', 'fitnescat' ], 
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'hide_empty' => true,  
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'number' => $tax_per_page,
   'offset' => $offset
];

$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

вывод пагинации для таксономий используя функционал wp для построения ссылок

```
$terms_count = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => [ 'post_tag', 'fitnescat' ],
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ]
);

$terms_count = count( $terms_count );
$big = 999999999;
$args = [
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => ceil( $terms_count / $tax_per_page ),
];

$result = paginate_links( $args );
echo $result;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121340/discussion-on-answer-by-darth-kyl--------).

Answer (score 1):

В get_terms есть параметры для этого number, offset

```
$per_page = 3;
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$taxonomy = 'post_tag';
$offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page ;
$args = array( 'number' => $per_page , 
              'offset' => $offset, 
              'taxonomy'  => array( 'post_tag', 'fitnescat' ),   
              'order' => 'ASC', 
              'hide_empty' => true,    
              'hierarchical' => true 
              );
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
```

И пагинация для этого

```
    $total_terms = wp_count_terms( array('taxonomy' => array( 'post_tag', 'fitnescat' ),   'hide_empty' => true) );
    $pages = ceil($total_terms/$per_page);

    // if there's more than one page
    if( $pages > 1 ):
        echo '<ul>';

        for ($pagecount=1; $pagecount <= $pages; $pagecount++):
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'page/'.$pagecount.'/">'.$pagecount.'</a></li>';
        endfor;

        echo '</ul>';

        // link to show all
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">show all</a>';
    endif;
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь. Не подскажите почему при выводе пагинации выдает ошибку Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in D:\OpenServer\domains\fitnes2\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 259

Comment: @АлексейПетров а что возвращает wp_count_terms ?

Comment: @АлексейПетров удалите параметр , 'hierarchical'  => true из wp_count_terms